# Spacing justify in Libreoffice writer: gaps between words

Tags: libreoffice

Using justify writing a text on libreoffice writer I obtain this

```
also the shape of the airfoil is
determined     by   requirements
contrasting.
```

I want to obtain this

```
also the shape of the airfoil is
determined by requirements contr
asting.
```

One white space max between words and
word broken even with broke grammatic
al rules at some point.

Is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you misunderstand how justify works. Yes, it stretches the whitespaces to make the text look even. Yes, if there are too many long words it looks ugly.

You probably want [auto-hyphenation](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/lo/text/swriter/guide/using_hyphen.html), which acts more or less like you've described your desired result.

Comment: perfect solution, thanks